# getting first page input value on second page slider using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, knockout.js

I have a 2 pages, first page with a form

```
<form action="index.php/moneyexchange/save_userinput" method="post">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;">
  <a type="submit" style="background-color:#fff; color:#66cccc;" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/money/firstpage">Borrow</a>
</form>
```

And in the second page I have a slider using KNOCKOUT JS functionality.

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id="ex2Slider" type="text" data-bind="sliderValue: {value: amount, min:0, max: 5000, step: 1, tooltip: 'always', formatter:formatter2}"
            style="display: none;">
```

What I want to do is get the Amount value from the first page and show it on the knockout js sliders.
Right now I am showing in the sliders a value of 2500.

```
self.amount = ko.observable(2500);
    var amount = ko.observable(2500);
    self.formatter1 = function(amount) {
      return amount + ' kk';
    }
```

Can someone help me in how to get the value from the first page and add to the observable of second page so the sliders start with that value. Thanks for the help. I dont mind if I can even bring the data from cookies, but what I am trying to do normally right now is load this data, to codeigniter controller like this,

```
public function save_userinput(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $form_data = $this->input->post();
    }
```

And then initialize it in the knockout js File which I have, but I need a proper way of doing it.

Comment: You will have to 1) preserve the value from the first page (send it to server and then get it back, store it in cookies), 2) on your second page read that value into variable `x` and pass `x` to `self.amount = ko.observable(x);` instead of `2500`. Or if your second page is loaded with ajax there is not problem at all. Also the `var amount = ko.observable(2500);` part is wrong - it will not be attached to your viewmodel so there is no point making it observable.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov yea I deleted the var which was not necessary, I am using codeigniter framework, so when I am clicking the button, can it be sent to the controller and getting the data from there?

Comment: Can't help you with codeigniter, sorry.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov even if I dont use codeigniter, how can I put it on the cookies and bring it to the knockout?

Comment: Are the two pages part of a single-page application, or does the browser actually do a separate page load for the 2nd page?

Comment: @RoyJ the browser does a seperate page load.

Comment: Does the 1st page form submit call the 2nd page, and pass it a query string?

Comment: @RoyJ  Nope it does not, I am not sure how to pass it to the 2nd page any way.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://websitetutorials.grafix.gr/php/php5/moving-information-from-page-to-page/